# After ajax call filter and sort is working but data is not updating

Tags: datatable, datatables

I am using datatable in my application. I am facing an issue like after ajax call filter and sort is working but the data is not updating. I will get every 15s once via ajax call. The dynamic data is not updating into datatable.

```
init:
    var table;

table = 
$('#table1').DataTable({ 
  "autoWidth": false,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bInfo": true,
  "bSort": true,
  "aaSorting": [[3, 'asc']],
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "sScrollY": 500px,
  "sScrollXInner": false,
  "bLengthChange": true,
  "iDisplayLength": -1,
});

$('#myInputTextField').keyup(function() {
    table.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

I am building the data in JavaScript append into data table `<tbody>` Ajax:

```
if(table != undefined){ table.search($('#myInputTextField').val()).draw(); }
```

Comment: So do you want to update your data table when someone tries to sort it?

Comment: There are several posts on Stack Overflow regarding this problem.  Have you looked at them?

Comment: Tim,I am thinking should i clear data table .It will resolve.

Comment: So you are proposing to clear the data and the redraw it?  That sounds like not such a bad strategy.

Comment: Tim, even that also not working

Comment: I got the solution.I cleared data-table then adding the new rows.       trArray=[mydata];                                                                               table.clear().draw();
table .rows.add(trArray).draw();

Comment: Maybe you can answer your own question.